# Create quote without stock validation

Tags: cart, price, custom, quote

For my project I need to empty current quote and add new products from quotation (custom module, and all programmatically).

But, when I add some products (5000 for my tests), I have an error because I don't have stock for this product.

For my test, I need to add product with custom price and custom quantity. 
At this moment, I have this code :

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $quoteItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($quoteItems as $item)
        $cart->removeItem($item->getId());

    // Nouveau panier
    $devisItems = Mage::getModel('devis/detail')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('devis_id', (int)$quote_id);
    foreach($devisItems as $item)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getOfferId());
        $cart->addProduct($product, 1);
    }
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made me on the good road !

Here the solution I found :

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $quoteItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($quoteItems as $item)
        $cart->removeItem($item->getId());

    // Nouveau panier
    $devisItems = Mage::getModel('devis/detail')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('devis_id', (int)$quote_id);
    foreach($devisItems as $item)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getOfferId());

        $stock_item = $product->getStockItem();
        $stock_item->setData('is_in_stock', true);
        $stock_item->setData('use_config_backorders', false);
        $stock_item->setData('backorders', '1');
        $stock_item->save();

        $cart->addProduct($product, 5000);
    }
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

I have to reactivate backorders for this product when I'll end my process.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't save product, just remove `$product->save();`, without it; will work

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you will not need to play with stock item, just set super mode for cart

Comment: It work without product update, I updated my answer

Comment: Saving $stock_item is necessary

Answer (score 0):

Please try below,

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote = $quote->setStoreId($store_id);
$quote->setIsSuperMode(true);

$productId  = 1;
$iqty       = 10;

$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = $productModel->load($productId);
$quote->addProduct($product, $iqty);

$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

Comment: Hello Nalin, I tried this code yesterday. But, it does not work : I have 400 products in stock but I want to add 5000 in cart. (error  message : The quantity for "product" is not available)

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: It does'nt work when I activate cart super mode.

Comment: Ohh, it's cart, you can set super mode for quote, sorry for wrong information. I have updated my answer, it will help anybody for future reference

Comment: Yes that's quote I want to create. Is it necessary to create cart before quote ?

Comment: You can directly create quote object and proceed

Comment: Yes, it works. But not with setIsSuperMode(). Can I add custom price just for this quote ?

Comment: setIsSuperMode is working with I apply that method to product object !

Comment: If it's working fine then please accept the answer, so it can help others as well